# Detect if character or integer in mips

Tags: mips

So my program receives a 32-bit integer input from user and changes it to hex and also exits when user inputs 0

I got a fully functional program, the problem is that I can't get it to show error when user inputs alphabets or symbol.

I'm using system call code 5 to read integer.
From my experiments, it treats every non-number input as 0.

So any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by _"non-number input"_? _Any_ value returned by syscall 5 is a valid 32-bit integer. Some of those values could _also_ be intepreted as characters in some character encoding; for example, the value 65 might be intepreted as `'A'`, but it's still also the value 65.

Comment: I have this code to exit on 0: "beq $t0,  0, exit" where $t0 is the value user input and whenever I enter an alphabet it exits

Comment: Ok, well SPIM/MARS might return 0 for anything that can't be parsed as an integer. In that case you may just have to use syscall 8 (read_string) instead and parse it yourself.

Comment: I've though about it, but was hoping there would be a simpler solution because I though it would be funny for the code for error checking to be as large as or larger than the code for the main function.

Comment: If you are using MARS have you considered using syscall 51 (rather than 5) to do the input? It will return a status value in $a1 that will tell you if what was read was an integer or not. You can learn more about it [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)